Propensity score matching with extremly small data size. Is there any alternative method that works with small data?
I have two groups, A and B, which represent two different imaging methods for detecting a rare disease. This is not a typical treatment-control setup; instead, it involves comparing the efficacy of these two imaging methods. Group A consists of 37 subjects, while Group B consists of only 9 subjects. The sensitivity for method A is 19% (7 true positives out of 37), whereas for method B it is 55% (5 true positives out of 9) at thershold value of 0.3 (see figure for outcome probabilties)
Despite imaging expert opinions suggesting that method B is superior in quality for disease detection, what are the feasible options for conducting a quantitative analysis to show that two methods differ? Specifically, can we use propensity score matching (PSM) to demonstrate that the observed difference in detection rates is attributable to the imaging methods rather than to associated covariates with disease? I am new to propensity score matching and received a suggestion to perform 1:2 matching to match covariates associated with disease. Is PSM a viable approach given the small cohort sizes? What are other options to show the observed differences in detection rate of disease for these two imaging methods?

I'm not sure if this will answer your question, but a long time ago I read a book by Hoyle called Statistical Strategies for Small Sample Research.  I no longer have the book, and I don't remember the details, but I do recall it being fairly good.

I doubt you can make any conclusion based on a sample that size. Just because it was challenging or expensive to collect or is the only sample of its kind does not justify its ability to make useful conclusions. PSM is among the worst methods for this kind of data because it involves discarding data, which is already so scarce. Regression analysis is better in this kind of scenario but even that will suffer with a sample this small. I would advise you to collect more data before performing any statistical analysis, let alone one that decreases precision further like PSM.

Sensitivity and similar measures suffer from all the same problems as accuracy as a KPI, especially (and not exclusively) in your situation of "unbalanced" data.
I would recommend you change to probabilistic classifications and evaluate these using proper scoring rules. You can threshold-weight them if you want to emphasize certain prediction regions - you may be less interested in a predicted probability around 0.1, but much more in higher ones. See Gneiting & Ranjan, 2011 for such modifications of scoring rules, and Reduce Classification Probability Threshold for thoughts on classification thresholds.
You can then try to get a measure of the variability of these scores (e.g., using leave one out cross validation) and see whether A and B differ significantly in scores, using standard t tests, or alternatives if you are concerned about your not very large sample size. (I personally would use a t test without hesitation in your case.)

Thank you for your suggestion. I have already selected a threshold of 0.3, resulting in a sensitivity of 19% for group A and 55% for group B. The model assigns higher probability scores to correctly classified subjects in group B (question updated with figure)
I have a question about the leave-one-out cross-validation process. Should I randomly drop a subject from the smaller group (B) and then compute the test results? Also, does this process assume that the model's detection results are independent of disease covariates and that there is no selection bias?

First off, I hope you have substantive grounds for your choice of a threshold, not just "which threshold maximizes sensitivity?" Sensitivity implicitly assumes a very specific cost structure. Second, LOOCV proceeds by removing each data point in turn, fitting to the rest and predicting the removed one - and then you can assess your scoring rule on that, and get multiple such scores and can work with their variability. Your model should be accounting for the impact of covariates, this is not a job for the LOOCV. Same for selection bias, this is a question of your data gathering step.
